# How can I use XML attribute to filter the XML node?

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to select the `<NewsData>` witch it's `<NewsPhoto>` has `[iType='Photo']"`

> XML

```
<NewsData>
   <NewsPhoto [iType='Photo']"></NewsPhoto>
</NewsData>
<NewsData>
       <NewsPhoto></NewsPhoto>
</NewsData>
<NewsData>
       <NewsPhoto [iType='Photo']"></NewsPhoto>
</NewsData>...
```

I use the Jquery filter, but the `FilterItem` is hard to use.

```
        var FilterItem = $(xml).find('NewsData').filter(function(){
            if($(this).children("NewsPhoto").attr('iType')=='Photo'){
                return this;
            }
        });
        console.log(FilterItem);
```

[image]
[image]
Please give me some advice!

Comment: The function argument of `.filter()` should `return true` inside the `if` statement, not `return this`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(xml).find("NewsData  NewsPhoto[iType='Photo']")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I need to create a new collection of the NewsData witch only has <NewsPhoto [iType='Photo']">. Just selector can't help me.

Comment: Above code will return an array of NewsData which has news photo iType ='Photo'.

If you share your xml  code, I can help you